# Как сделать Flat object?

Tags: javascript

FlatObject
Напишите функцию, которая возвращает новый объект,
в котором все примитивные элементы вложенных объектов были рекурсивно "подняты"(подняты = из вложенного объекта перемещены в текущий) до первого уровня.
[CODE](https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-field-nzplt?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: И в чем возникли трудности? Что пытались?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Данную задачу можно свести к задаче уменьшения вложенности массивов.

Для получения из объекта массива можно воспользоваться методом [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

Далее пройдемся по всем элементам и если элемент является объектом - рекурсивно повторим операцию.

В итоге вместо многоуровневого объекта, получится много уровневый массив.

Для уменьшения вложенности можно воспользоваться методом [`.flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap). Данный метод позволит сразу добавлять куски массива, не наращивая вложенность.

Для получения объекта из массива, можно воспользоваться методом [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)

В итоге код может выглядеть так:

```js
const obj = {
  a: {
    b: {
      c: 1,
      d: 2,
      e: 3
    },
    f: {
      g: 4,
      h: 5
    }
  },
  i: 6,
  j: 7
};

const flatObject = (obj) => {
  function flat(o) {
    return Object.entries(o).flatMap(([key, val]) => {
      if (typeof val === 'object') return flat(val);

      return [
        [key, val]
      ];
    });
  }

  return Object.fromEntries(flat(obj));
};

console.log(flatObject(obj)) // { c: 1, d: 2, e: 3, g: 4, h: 5, i: 6, j: 7 };
```